# Keyboard doesn't slide with view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

When the view is dismissed the keyboard slides after the view.

I created a video to demonstrate the problem.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISFL5G17coU'

Does anyone know why this happens

Comment: interesting, but i couldn't tell you without some code.

Comment: When are you telling the textfield(s) to resign firstresponder? If not in viewwilldisappear:, try it there.

Comment: I never tell the textfields to resignfirstresponder when the view disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `-(void) viewWillDisappear:` make sure you call `resignFirstResponder` on your textfield.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: That makes the keyboard go away while the view is going away. While it does work it's not how the other views are behaving.